# What should install to work with customization of DotnetNuke?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am new in DotnetNuke. I don't know which tool use for customize modules and other things in DotnetNuke.
Can Visual Studio(2013 or later version) use for it? or any specific tool use for it?

If possible, please suggest me link of download.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Visual Studio would be the tool of choice for most DNN Developers

I would recommend that you read the following links:

This is a module template provided by Chris Hammond
https://github.com/ChrisHammond/DNNTemplates

This is an in-depth tutorial on how to use said template:
http://www.chrishammond.com/Blog/itemid/2616/using-the-new-module-development-templates-for-dot

Comment: Do I need to install any extension in Visual Studio for it? If so, can you please provide me download link?

Comment: I have downloaded using all 3 links but none of them installed. I found extension from Tools--> Extension.. It's `Aspose DotnetNuke C# Compiled Module` and another is `DAL2`. Is it the same you have suggested?

Comment: What version of VS are you using - What Year?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2013. Do I need to upgrade?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2015 - Then install the extension via the Tools > Extension menu

Comment: Look for the Chris Hammond/Christoc templates.... https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bdd506ef-d5c3-4274-bf1d-9e673fb23484