# Content of webpage doesn't display in Module in DotnetNuke

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I am new in DotnetNuke. So, first of all I don't know all terminology. My problem is content of Webform.aspx doesn't display in Module.

Let me describe the steps so it can be easy to track the missing steps if any.

- 1- Created a project of DotnetNuke 7 C# Compiled Module. Path:
  F:\website\dnndev.me\desktopmodules\DNNModule2

  2- Added a WebForm1.aspx and add a line "Hello World"

  3- Build project, DNNModule2_00.00.01_Install.zip is generated in
  F:\websites\dnndev.me\DesktopModules\DNNModule2\DNNModule2\install

  4- Added extension in http://www.dnndev.me/Admin/Extensions. It added
  successfully in Modules.

  5- Created New Page and added DNNModule2 by drag and drop. But it
  doesn't display content "Hello World" of WebForm1.aspx.

Do I need to set any property while I am adding Module in New WebPage?

Also suggest if my flow is wrong. I will be happy to improve.

Thanks

Comment: You need to work with UserControls, not pages. Did you use a template?

Comment: @VDWWD I didn't use. Can you please suggest how to use template? Actually I am really confuse what is meaning of Template here in DotnetNuke? Do you mean design template?

Comment: Yes, a template that helps you build modules. Like the link in Mitchel Sellers answer. Or see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40260578/5836671) answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a DNN module to work properly you need to work with an .ascx user control.  Typically these will inherit from the PortalModuleBase class.  There are a few options, but that is the most common.

.aspx pages themselves can exist in DNN, however, they are ONLY available if you access them directly, and not through the module process.

Your user control, when setup should be part of the .dnn manifest and referenced with a `<controlkey/>` value.  (As in no control key defined, to be the default view of your module.)

If you are not using a template, [this one](https://christoctemplate.codeplex.com/) is a great example.